# How to search for a double-quote string in github?

Tags: regex, github

I want to search for literally the `"client"` word with the double quote included in my GitHub repository. The result includes `clients*` that don't have any quotes

When I put this search term on it, the search result always eliminates the double quotes. I even try to escape with `\` e.g. `"\"client\""` but not helping.

Comment: The second query [should have worked](https://github.com/search?q=%22%5C%22client%5C%22%22&type=code).

Answer (score 0):

According to the GitHub documentation at [Search on GitHub > GitHub Code Search > Code search syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax), using a backslash `\` to escape a double quote character when searching for an exact string is the correct usage:

> ### [Searching for quotes and backslashes](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#searching-for-quotes-and-backslashes)
>
> To search for code containing a quotation mark, you can escape the quotation mark using a backslash. For example, to find the exact string `name = "tensorflow"`, you can search:
>
> ```txt
> "name = \"tensorflow\""
> ```
>
> To search for code containing a backslash, `\`, use a double backslash, `\\`.
>
> The two escape sequences `\\` and `\"` can be used outside of quotes as well. No other escape sequences are recognized, though. A backslash that isn't followed by either `"` or `\` is included in the search, unchanged.
>
> Additional escape sequences, such as `\n` to match a newline character, are supported in regular expressions. See "[Using regular expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/github-code-search/understanding-github-code-search-syntax#using-regular-expressions)."

---

To illustrate this functionality, here's a link to a search result view for the query below, which searches within the repo that hosts the documentation above for the literal quoted string `"tensorflow"`:

```txt
repo:github/docs "\"tensorflow\""
```

[`https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agithub%2Fdocs%20%22%5C%22tensorflow%5C%22%22&type=code`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agithub%2Fdocs%20%22%5C%22tensorflow%5C%22%22&type=code)